# Why menu or item on right click can't configed by menu.xml?

Tags: openbox

```
ls  /home/debian8/.config/openbox/
lxde-rc.xml  menu.xml

file /usr/share/icons/Tango/32x32/apps/file-manager.png
/usr/share/icons/Tango/32x32/apps/file-manager.png: symbolic link to system-file-manager.png

file /usr/share/icons/Tango/32x32/apps/system-file-manager.png
/usr/share/icons/Tango/32x32/apps/system-file-manager.png: PNG image data, 32 x 32, 8-bit/color RGBA, non-interlaced
```

Here is my mouse right click on desktop.

[image]

Now i want to change the right click,menu.xml file was edited into the following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openbox_menu xmlns="http://openbox.org/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://openbox.org/                 file:///usr/share/openbox/menu.xsd">
    <menu id="root-menu" label="Openbox 3">
            <item label="PCMan" icon="/usr/share/icons/Tango/32x32/apps/file-manager.png">
                <action name="Execute">
                    <command>pcmanfm</command>
                </action>
            </item>
    </menu>
</openbox_menu>
```

The mouse right click remains unchanged after reboot,why?

Answer (score 1):

You're using LXDE as a Desktop in addition to Openbox.

These desktops catch the right click event and if they do not forward it Openbox doesn't see the right click event and can't shwo the menu.
You can compare it with a normal window (Browser or File manager) which also catch the event before the desktop.

The menu, which can be seen in the screenshot, is not one of Openbox, so either you find a way to configure this menu or you need a way to show the Openbox menu.

To show the Openbox menu you can use an event which is not caught by the desktop, normally all desktops catch all mouse events similar to normal windows.

What I did is to use the key combination <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> so I can open the menu at any time.

Here is the configuration to do

```
  <keybind key="W-a">
      <action name="ShowMenu">
          <menu>root-menu</menu>
      </action>
  </keybind>
```

You have to add it in your general Openbox config file  under `<keyboard>`.

Alternatively you could get rid of the Desktop, which is a rather radical option.

The config file is `~/.config/openbox/lxde-rc.xml`

Answer (score 1):

- In the desktop right-click menu choose `Desktop Preferences`
- Navigate to the tab `Advanced`
- Tick the first entry: `Show menus provided by window managers when desktop is clicked`
- Click the "Close" button.

Now a right-click on the desktop should bring up the openbox menu.

After every edit of menu file remember to issue the command `openbox --reconfigure` for the changes to take effect.